# Code runs on Jupyter notebook in chrome, don't in VSCode with the same environment

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

i'm new to coding so be patient please. If i run the same code with the same conda environment in Jupyter notebook and VSCode (Notebook/Python) i get different things.

- On jupyter notebook in chrome it works and help(display) shows the doc saying display takes 1 argument.
- On jupyter notebook in VSCode it says "display function takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)" and help(display) shows "display(..)".
- On Python in VSCode it says "name 'display' is not defined".

EDIT:
I tried again and this time on Jupyter Notebook in VSCode it says "no module named 'pytesseract'".
I'm going crazy, nothing has changed and it's still the same conda environment

Please help me to understand this. Thank you in advance. The code is:

```
import pytesseract
import PIL
from PIL import Image
def binarize(image_to_transform):
    out_image=PIL.Image.new(image_to_transform.mode, (image_to_transform.width,image_to_transform.height))

    for i in range(255):
        threshold=i
        temp_image=image_to_transform.convert("L")
        for x in range(temp_image.width):
            for y in range(temp_image.height):
                if temp_image.getpixel((x,y))< threshold:
                    temp_image.putpixel( (x,y), 0 )
                else:
                    temp_image.putpixel( (x,y), 255 )
        if len(pytesseract.image_to_string(temp_image))>len(pytesseract.image_to_string(out_image)):
            out_image=temp_image


    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(out_image))
    display(out_image)
    return None
binarize(Image.open('readonly/Noisy_OCR.PNG'))
```

Comment: Hey Alessio. I'm a developer on this extension, so maybe I can help. When the notebook is open what do you see in the top right corner? That should show what kernel you are using for your notebook.